# UIScrollview not scrolling even if I add contentSize for keypath?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, contentsize

Hey guys I have a UI Scrollview that is embedded in a view. However; even if I set the contentSize in the IB Keypath it still will not scroll?

Any suggestions?

```
    @interface DigitalVC ()
{
    NSArray *switchArrayOut;
    NSArray *switchArrayIn;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate;

    UIColor *custom1;
    UIColor *custom2;
    UIColor *custom3;
    UIColor *custom4;
}
@property (weak,nonatomic) NCBoardManager *manager;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *resetCounter;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *liveSwitch;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputLabel;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *inputLabel;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *counterLabel;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *outputSwitch0;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *outputSwitch1;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *outputSwitch2;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *outputSwitch3;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *outputSwitch4;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *outputSwitch5;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *outputSwitch6;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *outputSwitch7;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch0;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch1;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch2;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch3;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch4;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch5;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch6;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *inputSwitch7;
- (IBAction)resetCounter:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)outputChanged:(UISwitch *)sender;
- (IBAction)liveChanged:(UISwitch *)sender;
@end

@implementation DigitalVC
int counter = 0;
//////////////////////////////
#pragma mark View Lifecycle
//////////////////////////////


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Digital VC loaded");

    switchArrayIn = @[self.inputSwitch0,
                      self.inputSwitch1,
                      self.inputSwitch2,
                      self.inputSwitch3,
                      self.inputSwitch4,
                      self.inputSwitch5,
                      self.inputSwitch6,
                      self.inputSwitch7];

    switchArrayOut = @[self.outputSwitch0,
                       self.outputSwitch1,
                       self.outputSwitch2,
                       self.outputSwitch3,
                       self.outputSwitch4,
                       self.outputSwitch5,
                       self.outputSwitch6,
                       self.outputSwitch7,];


    //  Register for notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(boardNotifications:)
                                                 name:CONNECTED_NOTIFICATION
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(boardNotifications:)
                                                 name:DISCONNECTED_NOTIFICATION
                                               object:nil];


    _manager = [NCBoardManager sharedBoardManager];

    //  Set up callbacks
    __unsafe_unretained DigitalVC *digitalVC = self;
    [_manager setDigitalInputHandling:dispatch_get_main_queue()
                              filter:^(NCDigitalInput *input){ return YES; }
                             handler:^(NCDigitalInput *input){ [digitalVC setInput:input]; }];

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    custom1 = [UIColor whiteColor];
    custom2 = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    custom3 = [UIColor blackColor];
    custom4 = [UIColor colorWithRed:.97 green:.97 blue:.588 alpha:1.0];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[custom2 CGColor], (id)[custom1 CGColor], (id)[custom2 CGColor], nil];
    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
    gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self updateInput];
    [self updateOutput];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:FALSE];

    [self setColors];
    [self setOutputSwitches];
}
```

Image:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rh5pwc5ocs0du76/Screenshot%202014-02-26%2009.47.10.png

Comment: Please post your code that is relevant.

Comment: There is no code it is built with the storyboard editor. within the keypath.

Comment: I have a DigitalVC.m class that's dandy and controls it fine and controls the UI, I can however post a screenshot of the storyboard

Comment: @trumpetlicks Check that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting all of the auto-resizing visual options worked and fixed my problem. I do not know why (the red lines  in the box that scales the view for you)

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the useAutoLayout and autoResizeSubviews of both UIView and UIScrollview from the IB then try

Comment: Tried that, no-go-joe.

Comment: Really, only the autoResizeSubviews should matter with the UIScrollView, not the UIView.

Comment: put some bg color on scroll and then try to locate can you see it on view or not ?